# How to make a smooth background fill from left to right along with input and submit when hovering

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry for my poor english.
How to implement this? It is necessary to smoothly appear and disappear when pointing. I tried, but it turns out quite differently. it is necessary that it is not just filled in with a rectangle, but that it is rounded. also, so that when passing "input" and "submit", he also painted them over. everything is as in the picture
([image]

```css
.feedback {
  display:flex;
  padding: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, 
#000 50%, #FA5C45 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100%;
  transition:all 2s ease;

}

.title__block {
  width: 50%;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.feedback:hover {
    background-position: 0 100%;
}

h3 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="feedback">
  <div class="title__block"> 
    <h3> Оставьте заявку</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="form__block">
    <form>
      <input type="name" class="input">
      <input type="phone" class="input">
      <input type="submit" class="submit">


    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what is to happen to the inputs and submit elements on hover? I assume they don't get completely covered (else the user will never be able to input anything) - are they to get cleared or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it took me a while but i hope it will work for you :)

I changed it from `linear-gradient` to `radial-gradient`, the reason is because you can't get rounded shape with a `linear-gradient`.

Then I resized it a little bit so it looks almost the same as you showed us the screenshots, changed the background size to go off the screen , i tried to use `%` but it didn't work so instead of that i used `viewport` for both `width` and `height`.After that i changed the position so it goes out from the `viewport` range and on your `:hover` function just changed back the position so it fills up your `div`.

If you find the animation too slow, its because i put too big numbers into the `viewport` sizes, therefore if you want it to be faster, just change the `transition` value in your `.feedback` div to a smaller value.

https://codepen.io/qnecro/pen/PomdVLr

```
.feedback {
  display:flex;
  padding: 40px;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse, 
#000 40%, #FA5C45 40%);
  background-size: 500vw 300vh;
  background-position: -392vw 50%;
  transition:all 2s ease;
}

.title__block {
  width: 50%;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.feedback:hover {
  background-position: -288vw 50%;
}

h3 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

But be AWARE!

I made an Ellipse, so now it looks like this when you look at it from far away and you don't trigger your `:hover` function:
[image]

So when your `:hover` function triggers, you move the black Ellipse to the right side as the blue arrow shows you in your `:hover` function, you end up with this:
[image]

But if you change your `viewport` value to too big, it can end up looking like this:
[image]

Your div on the left side will be no longer covered by the black ellipse.

Answer (score 1):

For you issue better away use `pseudo-element` like extra layer. And for `input` tags to set `background: transparent`.

```css
.feedback {
  display: flex;
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: #fa5c45;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.feedback::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: calc(100% + 300px);
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 0 300px 300px 0 / 0 250px 250px 0;
  transform: translate(-110%, -50%);
  transition: all 2s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}

.feedback:hover::after {
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

.title__block {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.input[type='name'],
.input[type='phone'] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 0;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

::placeholder {
  color: white;
}

.feedback:hover {
  background-position: 0 100%;
}

h3 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="feedback">
  <div class="title__block">
    <h3>Оставьте заявку</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="form__block">
    <form>
      <input type="name" class="input" placeholder="Имя" />
      <input type="phone" class="input" placeholder="Телефон" />
      <input type="submit" class="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```